# can't upgrade api version of my facebook developer app

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to upgrade the api version of my facebook developer app by [API Upgrade Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/api_versioning/)

and I am getting following message:

> Your app hasn't made enough calls to the Graph API to show any info,
> or there are no changes for the methods you selected between v2.0 and
> v2.1

How can I upgrade my facebook app's api version?

Comment: I have the same problem upgrading from v2.4.